# Oscillatory Integrals near the Riemann singularity

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals, oscillatory-integral

The question comes from E. M. Stein. *Harmonic Analysis: Real-Variable Methods, Orthogonality, and Oscillatory Integrals*, we concerned about the highly oscillatory distribution
$$
D(x)=\mathrm{p.v.} \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}/x}}{x^\gamma},\quad x\in(0,\infty),\quad \gamma\in(0,2)
$$
and if $x>1$, we cant modified $D(x)$ to be smooth compact support hence we’ll omit it.

Now we deal with the Fourier transform of $D$:
$$
\hat{D}(\xi) = \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_\varepsilon^1
\frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}/x+\mathrm{i}x\xi}}{x^\gamma},\,\mathrm{d}x.
$$
By integration by parts, $\hat{D}(\xi)$ exists, let $\phi(x)$ be the phase function $\frac{1}{x}+x\xi$, since $\phi$ contains a nondegenerate critical points $x_0=\frac{1}{\sqrt\xi}$, we can use the *method of stationary phase*: let $a = x_0/2$, $b = 3x_0/2$, so:
$$
\hat{D}(\xi) = \lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_\varepsilon^a
+\int_a^b+\int_b^1 = I_1+I_2+I_3.
$$
By $|\phi'(x)|\gtrsim\xi$, hence by van der Corput lemma, $\int_b^1=\mathcal{O}(\xi^{\gamma/2-1})$, similarly, $\int_a^b = \mathcal{O}(\xi^{-3/4+\gamma/2})$. Hence the question is the oscillatory integral near the Riemann singularity $0$. Stein claimed “$\lim_{\varepsilon\to0}\int_\varepsilon^a = \mathcal{O}(\xi^{\gamma/2-1})$”:

[from page. 340](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bNhaF.png)

But
$$
I_1 = \int \frac{(\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi(x)})' }{\mathrm{i}x^\gamma\phi'(x)} = \frac{\mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi(x)}}{\mathrm{i}x^\gamma\phi'(x)}\biggr|^a_0 + \int \mathrm{e}^{\mathrm{i}\phi(x)}\Bigl(\frac{1}{\mathrm{i}x^\gamma\phi'(x)}\Bigr)'\,\mathrm{d}x
$$
the first one is $\mathcal{O}(\xi^{\gamma/2-1})$, but the magnitude function of the second is unbounded: $\frac{\mathrm{i} x^{1-\gamma } (-\gamma +\gamma  \xi  x^2+2)}{(\xi 
   x^2-1)^2}$, hence I can’t use method of stationary phase or
van der Corput lemma, but what Stein said made me think it was easy to estimate. Since I can’t deal with oscillatory integral near a singularity, please help.

Comment: $\frac{ x^{1-\gamma } (-\gamma +\gamma  \xi  x^2+2)}{(\xi 
   x^2-1)^2}$ is positive, you can bound the second integral by setting $i\exp(i\phi)\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: I'm sorry there was a typo in the description of the question (modified now): $\gamma\in(0, 2)$ instead of $(0,1)$, hence the function you mention is unbounded. Meanwhile, I'm also sorry that I'm not quite sure what you mean by $\exp(i\phi)\to1$. Can you explain it in detail?

Comment: I mean $|i e^{i\phi}|\le 1$, the second integral is bounded by $\frac{1}{x^{\gamma}\phi'(x)}|_{\epsilon}^a$ if the derivative is positive.

Comment: I understand it and thanks for your answer.